# Materialized view query contains unsupported feature Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, materialized-views

I am working on BigQuery trying to create a materialized view but I am getting an error and I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
  new_view 
  OPTIONS (enable_refresh = true, refresh_interval_minutes = 360) AS
WITH data as (SELECT
  brand,
  platform,
  version_a,
  version_b,
  date,
  sum(requests) as requests
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  brand != 'other'
  AND platform IS NOT NULL
  AND version_a IS NOT NULL
  AND version_a != ''
  AND version_b IS NOT NULL
  AND version_b != ''
  group by 1,2,3,4,5
)
SELECT
  brand,
  platform,
  version_a,
  max(version_b) AS version_b,
  min(date) AS first_date
FROM data
WHERE
 requests > 1000
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

The error is: `Materialized view query contains unsupported feature.`

I see that the error disappeared when I remove the sum on the code, but I am pretty sure that sum is allowed on a materialized view, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Materialized views perform well because they aim to read only the delta changes on the base table and add them to the most recent pre-computed results.

I would assume that summing the requests and then filtering by them makes it impossible for BQ to only observe the delta. If the current state of:
brand,
platform,
version_a,
version_b and
date has less than 1000 requests for a combination, it will drop it. However it is possible that at the next materialized view refresh, the value for that combination will be more than 1000. This makes it impossible to only look at deltas, so it would have to always reference back to the base table.

What if you calculated the values you want for all combinations of brand,   platform, version_a and then use a filter in the query that is referencing the materialized view.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro